# Network share files issue?

Tags: samba

I'm trying to set up file sharing so i can transfer files from my windows 10 computer to my Ubuntu 18.04 computer. I installed samba with

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

I made a folder on my hard drive, which is a different one then the OS, named it share. Made another folder in there called test. i right clicked share folder. Went to properties the local network share. Checked everything. ran

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Changed `work-group` to `SHARE` since that's what its call on the windows computer. at the bottom I added

```
\[sambashare\]
 &#x200B;
comment = Samba on Ubuntu
&#x200B;
path = /media/plex/Storage/Share
&#x200B;
read only = no
&#x200B;
browsable = yes
```

Then I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Then I did the command

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

then on the windows computer i right click start then hit run

```
type \\\\[10.0.0.26](https://10.0.0.26)
```

since thats the IP address for the Ubuntu computer

double click on the share folder

it says its no accessible. you may not have permission to use this network resource.

Answer (score 0):

Notes about my answer:

[a] I know nothing about plex.

[b] In the context of this question I'm assuming "plex" is also a user name.

[1] Right click the Share folder > Properties > Local Network Share and "unshare" the folder. Just undo everything you did here. Then run the following command to verify that you have no usershares:

```
net usershare info --long
```

[2] Edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and make your share definition look like this:

```
[sambashare]
path = /media/plex/Storage/Share
read only = no
guest ok = yes
force user = plex
```

[3] Save smb.conf

[4] Restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

[5] When you use Run from Windows 10 you can connect to this share using one of 2 ways. Using the ip address:

```
\\10.0.0.26\sambashare
```

Or using the mDNS name:

```
\\ubuntu-host-name.local\sambashare
```

*Change "ubuntu-host-name" to the actual host name of your Ubuntu machine - and don't forget the ".local" at the end.*